# How to Decrypt encrypted text in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, cryptojs

We have this code on encrypting/decrypting a particular message and I'd like to decrypt the value in Flutter (dart).

```
/* Encrypt text
 * @param text
 */
export const encrypt = (text: string): string => {
  const encJson = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(text), SECRET_KEY).toString();
  return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(encJson));
};

/* Decrypt text
 * @param ciphertext
 */
export const decrypt = (ciphertext: string): string => {
  const decData = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decData, SECRET_KEY).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  return JSON.parse(bytes);
};
```

I have tried the example mentioned in this article but could not make it work.
https://medium.com/@chingsuehok/cryptojs-aes-encryption-decryption-for-flutter-dart-7ca123bd7464

I really appreciate if anyone can help or point me out on what to change on my code.

Current code:

```dart
String decryptAESCryptoJS(String encrypted, String passphrase) {
  try {
    Uint8List encryptedBytesWithSalt = base64.decode(encrypted);

    Uint8List encryptedBytes =
        encryptedBytesWithSalt.sublist(16, encryptedBytesWithSalt.length);
    final salt = encryptedBytesWithSalt.sublist(8, 16);
    var keyndIV = deriveKeyAndIV(passphrase, salt);
    final key = encrypt.Key(keyndIV.item1);
    final iv = encrypt.IV(keyndIV.item2);
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(
        encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc, padding: "PKCS7"));
    final decrypted =
        encrypter.decrypt64(base64.encode(encryptedBytes), iv: iv);
    return decrypted;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

Tuple2<Uint8List, Uint8List> deriveKeyAndIV(String passphrase, Uint8List salt) {
  var password = createUint8ListFromString(passphrase);
  Uint8List concatenatedHashes = Uint8List(0);
  List<int> currentHash = Uint8List(0);
  bool enoughBytesForKey = false;
  Uint8List preHash = Uint8List(0);

  while (!enoughBytesForKey) {
    int preHashLength = currentHash.length + password.length + salt.length;
    if (currentHash.length > 0)
      preHash = Uint8List.fromList(currentHash + password + salt);
    else
      preHash = Uint8List.fromList(password + salt);

    currentHash = md5.convert(preHash).bytes;
    concatenatedHashes = Uint8List.fromList(concatenatedHashes + currentHash);
    if (concatenatedHashes.length >= 48) enoughBytesForKey = true;
  }

  var keyBtyes = concatenatedHashes.sublist(0, 32);
  var ivBtyes = concatenatedHashes.sublist(32, 48);
  return new Tuple2(keyBtyes, ivBtyes);
}

Uint8List createUint8ListFromString(String s) {
  var ret = new Uint8List(s.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    ret[i] = s.codeUnitAt(i);
  }
  return ret;
}

Uint8List genRandomWithNonZero(int seedLength) {
  final random = Random.secure();
  const int randomMax = 245;
  final Uint8List uint8list = Uint8List(seedLength);
  for (int i = 0; i < seedLength; i++) {
    uint8list[i] = random.nextInt(randomMax) + 1;
  }
  return uint8list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CryptoJS code unnecessarily Base64 encodes the ciphertext twice during encryption. So the most reasonable solution would be to fix the CryptoJS code.
In `encrypt()`, `encJson` is already the Base64 encoded ciphertext, i.e. the body of the `encrypt()` method should actually be:

```js
return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(text), SECRET_KEY).toString();
```

and analogously the body of `decrypt()`:

```js
const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, SECRET_KEY).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
return JSON.parse(bytes);
```

With this fix, successful decryption with the *unmodified* Dart code is possible.

---

If for some reason the CryptoJS code must not be changed, the Dart code in `decryptAESCryptoJS()` must also Base64 decode twice:

```dart
Uint8List encryptedBytesWithSalt = base64.decode(utf8.decode(base64.decode(encrypted)));
```

With this fix, the ciphertext of the *unmodified* CryptoJS code can be successfully decrypted.